# captured variable hides passed variable in lambda. how to unhide?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this example:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 100;
    std::cout<<[=,&a](int a,int b){return a+b;}(99,1);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `101` instead of my expectation of `100`.

I cant specify as so `[&a,=]` as it gives error.

How do i avoid the name hiding and refer to the parameter. i know changing the name is the option but i'm curious. also reference to standard will be helpful

EDIT:
i'm using gcc 4.7.1

EDIT:

here is the ideone link showing the demo. i used c++ 4.7.2 complier there
[ideone](http://ideone.com/jtz01b)

Comment: Can't you just **rename** one of the argument and the outer local variable?

Comment: yes i have mentioned that in my questioned but i'm curious as to why that can be done?

Comment: `[&,=]` pass all variables by reference **and** all of them by copy simultaneously ?! It's meaningless for me.

Comment: @MM. not that i meant [&a,=]

Comment: Why do you need the `&a` if, apparently, you don't intend to use the outer `a` in the lambda at all?

Comment: @sepp2k actually i was doing something else in the actual definition of the lambda. only for this example i changed it so.

Comment: +1, I'm tempted to think this is a bug

Comment: @AndyProwl is it that lambdas are designed so? i dont know but i'm not able to sleep

Comment: @Koushik: Honestly, I could not figure it out yet. Notice, that Clang returns `100`.

Comment: @AndyProwl i'm using MinGW GCC 4.7.1.

Comment: guys i have added the ideone link and the results are faulty there too. same output as mine

Comment: @Koushik GCC 4.7.2 and 4.8.0 produce the same results as in the question but VC++10 and VC++11 produce the expected results. I agree with Andy that this is a bug. You should consider [filing a bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious oh thank you so clang VC++10 & 11 are ok. i' file a bug right away and please consider making that your answer and provide closure to this.

Comment: @Koushik I added an answer but it made me feel dirty.

Comment: @AndyProwl thank you for your (rightful)prediction.:)

Comment: Whether or not it is a bug, it is definitely bad coding style that will confound future maintainers of the code. Change the variable or parameter name to avoid the collision.

Comment: Downvoted for an example (and GCC bug report) that is missing `#include <iostream>`, making extra work for people trying to reproduce the problem. Just include the flipping header in the example!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not find anything related to lambdas in the standard that would indicate your results are the expected behavior. I agree with Andy's comment that this is a bug in GCC. GCC 4.7.2 on Linux, GCC 4.7.2 from MinGW, and GCC 4.8.0 from MinGW produce the same results as in the question but VC++10 and VC++11 produce the expected results.

You should consider [filing a bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)

Answer (score 3):

Since the parameter doesn't have a scope that you can name, you can't use scope resolution operator to disambiguate, nor `this` or any other such means. Therefore, it's impossible to disambiguate this scenario the way you want. You'll just have to not give your variables horrible and clashing names.

Comment: i agree but this is somthing that i came across unknowingly when i was debugging my code. but even then i believe that the parameter would hide the captured variable.i have already changed in my code but got really curious.

Answer (score 1):

How do I print out the outer `a` here, but in the inner scope?

```
int a = 1;
{
    int a = 2;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

You either change the name of one of the variables - or you don't.

The same goes for your lambda.

(I apologize that I can't reference the standard like you requested - I don't have it.)

Comment: no actually the outer a is getting printed not the inner. see the question. if you need clarification please let me know

Comment: Oh - that's really weird. So the captured `a` is overriding the parameter `a`. That might be a compiler bug?