# Lambda expression in c++, OS X's clang vs GCC

Tags: macos, gcc, c++11, clang, lambda

A particular property of c++'s lambda expressions is to capture the variables in the scope in which they are declared. For example I can use a declared and initialized variable c in a lambda function even if 'c' is not sent as an argument, but it's captured by '[ ]':

```
 #include<iostream>
 int main ()
 {int c=5; [c](int d){std::cout<<c+d<<'\n';}(5);}
```

The expected output is thus 10. The problem arises when at least 2 variables, one captured and the other sent as an argument, have the same name:

```
 #include<iostream>
 int main ()
 {int c=5; [c](int c){std::cout<<c<<'\n';}(3);}
```

I think that the 2011 standard for c++ says that the captured variable has the precedence on the arguments of the lambda expression in case of coincidence of names. In fact compiling the code using GCC 4.8.1 on Linux the output I get is the expected one, `5`. If I compile the same code using apple's version of clang compiler (clang-503.0.40, the one which comes with Xcode 5.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.4) I get the other answer, `3`.

I'm trying to figure why this happens; is it just an apple's compiler bug (if the standard for the language really says that the captured 'c' has the precedence) or something similar? Can this issue be fixed?

**EDIT**

My teacher sent an email to GCC help desk, and they answered that it's clearly a bug of GCC compiler and to report it to Bugzilla. So Clang's behavior is the correct one!

Comment: I can't find anything in the standard that defines what the correct behavior should be.

Comment: (1) This is only a problem for language lawyers. Normal people get thrown out of the code review with stuff like this. Just don't do that. (2) Where does the standard say that? (3) [Different people have different expectations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798079/captured-variable-hides-passed-variable-in-lambda-how-to-unhide). This is most likely a bug in g++. (4) Just don't do that.

Comment: It would be logical for the parameter to take precedence as I like to think of the captured variables as members of a class and the lambda function as the `operator()` member function.

Comment: @n.m. I know that this is a trivial issue that could be resolved by a simple new assignation of names, but i'm interested in it.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae Personally i think that the standard text is not very clear on this point such as Galik quoted below, but it was stated in my c++ class at university that the correct behavior is GCC's one. Reading Stroustrup's book about c++ it seems that lambda expressions were meant to be an alternative to struct object with a call operator, as quamrana says, so it's for me unclear whether GCC or clang is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C++11 Standard, 5.1.2 "Lambda expressions" [expr.prim.lambda] #7:

> The *lambda-expression*’s *compound-statement* yields the *function-body* (8.4) of the function call operator,
> but for purposes of name lookup (3.4), determining the type and value of `this` (9.3.2) and transforming *id-expression*s
> referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using `(*this)` (9.3.1),
> the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*.

Also, from 3.3.3 "Block scope" [basic.scope.local] #2:

> The potential scope of a function parameter name (including one appearing in a *lambda-declarator*) or of
> a function-local predefined variable in a function definition (8.4) begins at its point of declaration.

Names in a capture list are not declarations and therefore do not affect name lookup. The capture list just allows you to use the local variables; it does not introduce their names into the lambda's scope. Example:

```
int i, j;
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    [](){ i; }; // Error: Odr-uses non-static local variable without capturing it
    [](){ j; }; // OK
}
```

So, since the parameters to a lambda are in an inner block scope, and since name lookup is done in the context of the lambda expression (not, say, the generated class), the parameter names indeed hide the variable names in the enclosing function.

Comment: Note regarding Galik's answer: "It is unclear from my reading of the standard if this transformation should take precedence over parameter symbol lookup." Logically, you can't tell whether the id-expression is an odr-use of something until you know what the id-expression refers to. So first it is determined what the name refers to, and then (if it refers to a captured entity) the specified transformation happens.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of the c++11 standard's points below:

> ***5.1.2 Lambda expressions***
>
> ***3*** The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called
>   the closure type — whose properties are described below.
>
> ...
>
> ***5*** The closure type for a lambda-expression has a public inline function call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters and return type are
>   described by the lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause and
>   trailing-return-type respectively. This function call operator is
>   declared const (9.3.1) if and only if the lambda-expression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by mutable.
>
> ...
>
> ***14*** For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non static data member is declared in the closure type

A lambda expression like this...

```
int c = 5;

[c](int c){ std::cout << c << '\n'; }
```

...is roughly equivalent to a class/struct like this:

```
struct lambda
{
    int c; // captured c

    void operator()(int c) const
    {
        std::cout << c << '\n';
    }
};
```

So I would expect the parameter to hide the captured member.

***EDIT:***

In point ***14*** from the standard *(quoted above)* it would seem the data member created from the captured variable is *** *unnamed* ***. The mechanism by which is it referenced appears to be independent of the normal identifier lookups:

> ***17*** Every id-expression that is an odr-use (3.2) of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type.

It is unclear from my reading of the standard if this transformation should take precedence over parameter symbol lookup.

So perhaps this should be marked as ***UB*** *(undefined behaviour)*?

Comment: Looking at this now I think it is inaccurate. Point ***14*** of the standard says the data member is "unnamed". If the data member is "unnamed" then how can the parameter's name hide its name? So when a captured member is referred to by its capture name it must be using and alternative way to reference the actual anonymous data member. I need to hunt through the standard to see what takes preedence in this case.

Comment: The UB would probably explain why there is a different behavior between the two compilers. I'm also waiting an answer from my c++ teacher who assured me that in the standard is quoted that GCC behavior is the right one.